How to schedule a Powershell script in windows task scheduler for collect disk drive information from remote computer
I want to schedule a task in windows task scheduler to get disk drive information from a remote computer. If I run the script manually then I am getting the desired information but when running the script from task scheduler then getting no output but task is completing successfully.

$reportPath = "D:\Report.txt"

Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName 172.31.x.x | Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}| Out-String | Add-Content -Path $reportPath

I have created a task in task scheduler with run with highest privileges. But not getting the required information.
Action Details: powershell -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File D:\ResourceReport.ps1




Do have pretty much the same here but working fine : powershell.exe -file path_to_file -NoProfile -NoLogo       "powershell.exe" used instead. I would advise to use start-transcript | stop-transcript to see what is the exact output while running as scheduled task.

The task is running as SYSTEM and may therefore not have permissions for WMI operations on other computers. Run with a user identity that you know to have the required permissions.
